# Navigate to symbol in file missing keyboard shortcut

Tags: navigation, webstorm

I just started evaluating WebStorm and I am trying to find a mechanism of Navigating to a symbol in the current file only.

Comment: Try `Navigate | File Structure`

Comment: Yup I saw this, however I am just looking for a command to navigate to an item in the current file, sort of the same thing that ReSharper gives in Visual Studio

Comment: Nor familiar with Resharper -- how does that feature work there? Any links/gifs are welcome